What design is this: repeated, nested, other?
I've got a bit of a weird data set that at first glance, looks just like repeated measures. I'm hoping figure out if this is a special class of a more common type of model (e.g. repeated measures, nested, crossover) or what the jargon is so I can read up on it to make sure I analyze it correctly.
In this study there are observations that occur through time on the same unit, but treatments are not all applied at time=0 , the sample units have treatments applied through time, rather than at the outset. Treatments are applied at the same time, regardless of sample unit, but not until a specific time point.
For example, if there are 3 treatments, A, B, and C, and repeated measurements at T1, T2, T3, T4. A is applied before T1 , B after T1 but before T2, and C after T2 but before T3, and the applied treatments are A, B, C, A+B, and A+B+C, B+C, and a control. It seems to that Treatments B, C, and B+C are all effectively controls when measured before T2 and C is a control up to T2.
Is there a special term for this? It's not a clear-cut repeated measures as treatments effectively differ through time, and it doesn't really seem like a crossover either. I know it's some kind of random effects model, but I'm not too sure if I need to nest anything, or what, if anything should be nested. Am I just overthinking it?

Do all units receive all treatments (A, B, and C)?

It depends on what you mean. In the above example, there are 7 levels of treatment (including a control) and 4 blocks. Every one of the 7 levels appears in each block, but not all sample units will receive every sequential treatment. Does that make sense?

Sorry, but this is the first time you have used the word block. Can you be more explicit about how the blocks are defined?

Sorry. I'm trying to avoid misleading terms like plot. Think of it just as a replicate.

It would be helpful if you could edit in a small dataframe with the same structure as your data.
